# Tab Doesn't Enter with .select2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2

If a user creates a custom option and then clicks tab then that custom option isn't entered.

The user has to hit enter and then tab if he wants to move onto the next element in the form, which I'd like to reduce the unnecessary step of hitting enter first if possible.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@lifetime, html: { data: { modal: true } }) do |f| %> 

  <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:name, @collection, :last, :first, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true) %>

<% end %>

<script>
  $('#lifetime_name').select2({
    placeholder: "Enter Challenge",
    theme: "bootstrap",
    allowClear: false,
    tags: true,
    multiple: false,
  });
</script>
```

So in other words, if a user writes in a custom option, how can we make tab mean to "enter and move onto next element"? If the user chooses a default option then this problem doesn't exist, but in most cases users will want to create their own custom option.

Comment: Note that TAB traditionally closes a select box, which is what Select2 does. Unfortunately Select2 doesn't automatically select the option when you close the dropdown, but it does provide the `selectOnClose` option for you to be able to enable this.

Comment: How can I integrate `selectOnClose`? Do I add that to the script or in the `f.grouped_collection_select` or somewhere else? Thanks for your insight @KevinBrown!

Comment: You add that when initializing Select2, in the JS. Assuming that is what you are looking for, I can write up a more detailed answer later when I'm on a computer.

Comment: Yea that would be perfect and then I can give you the credit too @KevinBrown